# KML Extended Data to Folium Marker Popups

Tags: python, kml, folium

I have the following example KML which has extended data within in. I have worked out how to create a folium map from a KML, plot the points (markers). My goal is to be able to extract the geometries from the KML with popups that show the extended data (SimpleData) attribute names and variables. The end goal is to have a folium map that looks similar to the map (see link below KML).

How do I extract those particular values in extended data into a folium marker popup?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <Schema name="TrailHeadType" id="TrailHeadTypeId">
    <SimpleField type="string" name="TrailHeadName">
      <displayName><![CDATA[<b>Trail Head Name</b>]]></displayName>
    </SimpleField>
    <SimpleField type="double" name="TrailLength">
      <displayName><![CDATA[<i>The length in miles</i>]]></displayName>
    </SimpleField>
    <SimpleField type="int" name="ElevationGain">
      <displayName><![CDATA[<i>change in altitude</i>]]></displayName>
    </SimpleField>
  </Schema>
  <Placemark id="foo" targetId="bar">
    <name>__NAME__</name>
    <address>__ADDRESS__</address>
    <Snippet>__SNIPPET__</Snippet>
    <description>__DESCRIPTION__</description>
    <Style>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <!--
        XHTML in CDATA must conform to the HTML Compatibility guidelines as
        detailed in http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines. See in particular section
        C2, which requires <br /> over <br>.
        -->
        <text><![CDATA[
          <b>$[name]</b><br /><br />
          <i>$[description]<i><br /><br />
          The $[TrailHeadType/TrailHeadName/displayName] is
          <i>$[TrailHeadType/TrailHeadName]</i><br />
          The trail is $[TrailHeadType/TrailLength] miles<br />
          The climb is $[TrailHeadType/ElevationGain] meters<br /><br />
          $[geDirections]
        ]]></text>  <!-- TODO: decide on $[geDirections -->
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="holeNumber">
        <value>1</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holeYardage">
        <value>234</value>
      </Data>
      <SchemaData schemaUrl="#TrailHeadTypeId">
        <SimpleData name="TrailHeadName">Mount Everest</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="TrailLength">347.45</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ElevationGain">10000</SimpleData>
      </SchemaData>
    </ExtendedData>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

[Picture of folium map and popup which I am trying to 'replicate'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC1pi.png)